Escape character in xml when using xslt value-of
I have the following example soap webservice:
<CreateTask >
        <taskDetails>comments$Ref: 1010000&#xD;Small items for collection: &amp;amp; &#xD;Item location: Front of property&#xD;Access issues: Yes&#xD;Details of access issues: &#xD;#</taskDetails>
</CreateTask>

Which I generate using the following:
<CreateTask>
   <taskDetails>comments$<xsl:value-of select="//dform:field[dform:name='comments']/dform:value" />#</taskDetails>
<CreateTask>

comments is user entered data so could contain the following characters
" &quote;
' &apos;
< &lt;
> &gt;
& &amp;

How do i escape <xsl:value-of select="//dform:field[dform:name='comments']/dform:value" /> so that I don't get any issues?

What kind of issues do you have or fear? An xsl:value-of creates a text node, if you serialize the XSLT result tree any serializer for output method xml or html will take care of escaping any characters requiring that.

Also, you can use a CData section for that.
